# jQuery FeatureList plugin

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using the FeatureList jQuery plugin by jQueryglobe and I've run into a some kind of problem. Since jQueryglobe is closed now I can't ask them for support.

Here are the files that I used:
http://www.mediafire.com/?q7cn6y4tkdd75jd

[image]

How can I make the link inside the content of the PROGRAMMING tab show the content of the next tab which is APPLICATIONS, or make it work on any other links outside the content?